# NoReverseMatch at /seller_page/2/

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

by clicking the close button only the seller should be able to close the auction, but here the keys are displayed for everyone and when you click on them, this error occurs. What's wrong?

The error I'm getting is related to another part of the code that works fine.

> Inversion not found for 'add' with arguments '(,)'. 1 tried pattern: ['add/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']
> File "C:\Users\Desktop\work on it\commerce\auctions\views.py", line 195, in seller_page
> return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', {'seller_offers': seller_offers})

Thanks in advance for taking the time to respond:)

models.py:

```
class List(models.Model):
choice = (
    ('d', 'Dark'),
    ('s', 'Sweet'),
)
user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
description = models.TextField()  
category = models.CharField(max_length=64)      
first_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/", null=True)      
image_url = models.CharField(max_length=228, default = None, blank = True, null = True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= choice)
seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
winner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='winner')
active_bool = models.BooleanField(default = True)

class Bid(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offered_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, 
      decimal_places=2)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

views.py:

```
def seller_page(request, product_id):
    seller_offers = get_object_or_404(Bid, pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        offer_id = request.POST.get('offer_id')
        offer = get_object_or_404(Bid, pk=offer_id)
        offer.is_closed = True
        offer.save()
    return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', 
{'seller_offers': seller_offers})
```

product_detail.html:

```
<ul>
    {% for offer in offers %}
        <li>{{ offer.user.username }} offered ${{ offer.offered_price }}</li>  
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'seller_page'  offer.id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="offer_id" value="{{ offer.id }}">
            <button type="submit">Close Offer</button>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

urls.py:

```
path('seller_page/<int:product_id>/', views.seller_page, name='seller_page')
```

And if I try to add this code to customize the button to the for loop in the template and place the form in it , the close button is no longer displayed.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user == product.seller  and  product.active_bool == True %}
```

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem The error I'm getting is related to another part of the code that works fine. This is the error: Inversion not found for 'add' with arguments '(,)'. 1 tried pattern: ['add/(?P<productid>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Comment: @Zatigem I log in with two different accounts and check.
I don't know how to do it in my code.

Comment: @Zatigem yes but  You can check this by logging in as a user.

Comment: @Zatigem No....
I don't have a problem with users logging in. They register in the login like a normal site.
But to sell, only the seller must see the key to close the auction.
Here is the sell button that gives the error and this button is visible to everyone.
So The button must be personalized.

Comment: @Zatigem Sorry, the chat page is not loading.

Comment: Try to debug: what is the output of `{{ user.is_authenticated }}` , `{{ user }}` , `{{ product.seller }}` , `{{ product.active_bool }}` outside the if ?

Comment: @Zatigem Either it gives the same error or it does not display the button at all.
I changed the code a little, please check this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77607416/22267432)

Answer (score 0):

in `views.py`, **seller_offers** is set as context variable, but in `auctions/product_detail.html`, it is being referred as **offers**

So change your `auctions/product_detail.html` like below,

```html
<ul>
{% for offer in seller_offers %}
    <li>{{ offer.user.username }} offered ${{ offer.offered_price }}</li>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'seller_page'  offer.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="offer_id" value="{{ offer.id }}">
        <button type="submit">Close Offer</button>
    </form>
    
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

A quick suggestion,

for seller_page function in `views.py`, [get_object_or_404](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get_object_or_404-method-in-django-models/) function gets only a single object from DB, so in html template you can avoid using for loop

in `views.py`,

```py
def seller_page(request, product_id):
seller_offers = get_object_or_404(Bid, pk=product_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    offer_id = request.POST.get('offer_id')
    offer = get_object_or_404(Bid, pk=offer_id)
    offer.is_closed = True
    offer.save()
return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', {'offer': seller_offers})
```

in html,

```html
<p>{{ offer.user.username }} offered ${{ offer.offered_price }}</p>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'seller_page'  offer.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="offer_id" value="{{ offer.id }}">
    <button type="submit">Close Offer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It gives the same error and the close button is visible to all.

Comment: And for the second way, if I change offer.id to product.id, it gives this error: the 'id' field expected a number, but received ''. And if I don't change it, it gives the same error as the first one.

Comment: ok, instead of {{ offer.id }}, can u change this to {{ offer.product_id }} in html template

If possible, could you share your model details as well

Comment: All code changes and models added. Please check the question again.