# Page not found (404)/Request Method: POST

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Only the seller should be able to sell the item by clicking the button and no one else can offer a price after that.

Also, the winner must be specified here and the winner can view their products by entering the product page and also viewing the winners page.

The winners page is also in the layout format and from there we should be able to see the product specifications that are in win.html.

But now, by clicking on the button, it shows the error that I wrote.

**Please tell me what to do to fix it.**

***thanks:)***

> Page not found (404)
> No List matches the given query.
> Request Method:    POST
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/off/
> Raised by:  auctions.views.off

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def win(request, username):
    try:
        your_win = List.objects.filter(user = username)
    except:
        your_win = None

    return render(request, "auctions/win.html",{
         "user_winlist" : your_win,
    })


@login_required(login_url="login")
def off(request):
    product = request.GET.get('productid', False)
    users = Bid.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    if users == (List.user): 
        product.is_closed = True 
        product.save()
        return win(request, request.user.username)
    
    
    return product_detail(request,product)
```

product_detail.html:

```
<ul>
    {% for offer in offers %}
        <li>{{ offer.user.username }} offered ${{ offer.offered_price }}</li>  
        {% if user.id == user.id %}
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'off'  %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ product }}">
                    <button type="submit">Close Offer</button>
                </form>
                {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

urls.py:

```
path("win/<str:username>/", views.win, name="win"),
path("off/", views.off, name="off"),
```

models.py:

```
class List(models.Model):
    choice = (
        ('d', 'Dark'),
        ('s', 'Sweet'),
    )
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()  
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)      
    first_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/", null=True)      
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=228, default = None, blank = True, null = 
                   True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= choice)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            related_name='winner')
    active_bool = models.BooleanField(default = True)

class Bid(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offered_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

layout.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'win' user.username %}">My Winnings</a>
            </li>
{% endif %}
     
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create' %}">Create List</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please also include `product_detail` function in your question. I suspect there is a `get_object_or_404` query there that returns this error.

Comment: In your off view, I can see `if users == (List.user)`. You need to get the instance before trying to get it’s attribute `user`.

Comment: @Temi The  instance is received in the first line of the shutdown function. is it correct?

Comment: @Ehsan88 Yes, the first line does that, but the rest of the code does other things. product=get_object_or_404 (List, pk=product_id)  where product_id is the function input.

Comment: @Temi And if I put this code instead of the first line. [product=get_object_or_404 (List, pk=product_id)] ​​Clicking on the button will display this error. Field id expected a number but got <List: List object (1)>.The error goes back to the first line of the product_detail function, which is exactly the same code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you used `name="product"` in the form but you're getting "productid" in the view:

`product = request.GET.get('productid', False)`.

Please check the `product` variable here I guess it's `False`. Two tips:

1. Return an error like a bad request error when there is no `productid` in the request for better debugging
2. Use consistent namings in forms and across functions to avoid errors like this

Comment: If I change this line of code from the off function to this code `product = get_object_or_404(List, pk=product_id)`. By clicking on the button, this error will be displayed. `Field 'id' expected a number but got <List: List object (1)>`